# Changing ruby controller variable based on input from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I define

```
 @variable1= '1'
```

in controller. In view, i call <%=@variable1%> and it show 1.
Now I click button to call

```
def change_variable
@variable1= '2'
end
```

what do I do to see '2' in view?

Comment: What are you rendering in the view associated with change_variable?

Comment: I'm new to ruby on rails,please tell me how can I just change value of @variable1 and don't do anything else

Comment: You cannot just change the value of @variable1, you can make an AJAX call or just create a new route and new view for `change_variable` action.

Comment: How can I update value of @variable1 and show change in same view ? I really need it.

Comment: AJAX is what you're looking for, you can read more about it in the documentation [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Answer (score 1):

The ruby code you have posted only runs at the time the page is being generated.

Once it is sent to the browser it becomes a static page.

In order to run the `change_variable` method you are referring to an http request of some description needs to be made (e.g. submit button, XMLHttpRequest etc.)

If you want the variables to change on the actual page, you will need to look into some javascript solutions.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example?I have tried this for a day and got nothing.

Comment: The amount of information and concepts required to get what you are talking about is unfortunately too much to be able to do on StackOverflow.  Perhaps you could start with some videos on Railscasts, such as this one http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript